# Is it ok for others to see your AdMob app-id or ad-id's? Using github for a project

Tags: github, admob, open-source

This is probably a stupid question but I'm developing a project with GitHub and was wondering if it was ok for others to see your AdMob app-id and ad-id's? I assume the worse that could happen is they use it in their app and you get money from it, but I don't know I'm still new to this.

Comment: thank you so much! I tried searching and googling for hours and came up short.